# negation handling in R, how can I replace a word following a negation in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, tm, negation

I'm doing sentiment analysis for financial articles. To enhance the accuracy of my naive Bayes classifier, I'd like to implement negation handling.

Specifically, I want to add the prefix "not_" to the word following a "not" or "n't"

So if there's something like this in my corpus:

```
 x <- "They didn't sell the company."
```

I want to get the following:

```
"they didn't not_sell the company."
```

(the stopword "didn't" will be removed later)

I could find only the `gsub()` function, but it doesn't seem to work for this task.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: `string <- "They didn't sell the company."`


`gsub("n't", " not", string)`

Comment: oh you want to *keep* "didn't" in there?

Comment: anyway, this give you exactly what you asked for `gsub("n't ", "n't not_", string)`

Comment: When you say things like `I could find only the gsub() function, but it doesn't seem to work for this task.` It's useful to see the code you tried so we know what you're thinking.  This mistake gives a ton of valuable information in diagnosing and addressing the problems.

Comment: @rawr Both those comments should be an answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, I want to add the prefix "not_" to the word following a
>   "not" or "n't"

```
str_negate <- function(x) {
  gsub("not ","not not_",gsub("n't ","n't not_",x))
}
```

Or I suppose you could use strsplit:

```
str_negate <- function(x) {
  str_split <- unlist(strsplit(x=x, split=" "))
  is_negative <- grepl("not|n't",str_split,ignore.case=T)
  negate_me <- append(FALSE,is_negative)[1:length(str_split)]
  str_split[negate_me==T]<- paste0("not_",str_split[negate_me==T])
  paste(str_split,collapse=" ")
}
```

either way gives you:

```
> str_negate("They didn't sell the company")
[1] "They didn't not_sell the company"
> str_negate("They did not sell the company")
[1] "They did not not_sell the company"
```

Comment: You can do this in base with `gsub("(?<=(?:\\bnot|n't) )(\\w+)\\b", "not_\\1", x, perl=T)`. No splitting necessary.

Comment: Agreed no splitting necessary.  Right after submitting I thought of a regex method that avoids back-referencing, which can be hard to follow sometimes.

Comment: True. I added the look behind because i originally wanted to be able to get rid of the word as well.