# Negation in R, how can I replace words following a negation in R?

Tags: r, regex, nlp, pcre

I'm following up on a question that has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811580/negation-handling-in-r-how-can-i-replace-a-word-following-a-negation-in-r) about how to add the prefix "not_" to a word following a negation.

In the comments, MrFlick proposed a solution using a regular expression `gsub("(?<=(?:\\bnot|n't) )(\\w+)\\b", "not_\\1", x, perl=T)`.

I would like to edit this regular expression in order to add the *not_* prefix to all the words following "not" or "n't" until there is some punctuation.

If I'm editing cptn's example, I'd like:

```
x <- "They didn't sell the company, and it went bankrupt"
```

To be transformed into:

```
"They didn't not_sell not_the not_company, and it went bankrupt"
```

Can the use of backreference still do the trick here? If so, any example would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: why the `perl` tag tho?

Comment: @Flying_whale, They meant [tag:pcre], which R can be instructed to use. (The `perl=T` aka `perl=TRUE` above.) Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\bnot|n't|\G(?!\A))\s+\K(\w+)\b
```

and replace with `not_\1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2UcFyL/3).

**Details**

- `(?:\bnot|n't|\G(?!\A))` - either of the three alternatives:

  - `\bnot` - whole word `not`
  - `n't` - `n't`
  - `\G(?!\A)` - the end of the previous successful match position
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `(\w+)` - Group 1 (referenced to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): 1+ word chars (digits, letters or `_`)
- `\b` - a word boundary.

[R demo](https://ideone.com/TWRERI):

```
x <- "They didn't sell the company, and it went bankrupt"
gsub("(?:\\bnot|n't|\\G(?!\\A))\\s+\\K(\\w+)\\b", "not_\\1", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "They didn't not_sell not_the not_company, and it went bankrupt"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should split the string on the punctuation you want. For example:

```
x <- "They didn't sell the company, and it went bankrupt. Then something else"
x_split <- strsplit(x, split = "[,.]") 
[[1]]
[1] "They didn't sell the company" " and it went bankrupt"        " Then something else"
```

and then apply the regex to every element of the list `x_split`. Finally merge all the pieces (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal, but gets the job done:

```
x <- "They didn't sell the company, and it did not go bankrupt. That's it" 

gsub("((^|[[:punct:]]).*?(not|n't)|[[:punct:]].*?((?<=\\s)[[:punct:]]|$))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\s", 
     " not_", x, 
     perl = TRUE)

# [1] "They didn't not_sell not_the not_company, and it did not not_go not_bankrupt. That's it"
```

**Notes:**

This uses the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` trick to avoid any pattern you don't want to regex to match. This basically replaces every space with `not_` except for those spaces where they fall between:

1. Start of string or punctuation and `"not"` or `"n't"` *or*
2. Punctuation and Punctuation (not followed by space) or end of string